# High performance library for bit-wise operations?

Tags: c++, c, performance, bit-manipulation

Dealing with very large bool data set, try to use bit-wise operation to handle it, looking for some library that dealing with bit-set that can:

1. Dynamic set, and can be passed by pointers or references.
2. Read and write bitwisely.
3. Count set bits and fast.

Obviously `std::bitset`'s functionalities are too limited for that, any recommendations?

Comment: Did you have a look at boost bitset?

Comment: @leemes Just looking at it at the moment, but open to other options, I am very conern about the performance issues there since the data set is very large and there are alot sum() like options on it.

Comment: I think boost bitset (or maybe bitfield, bitvector, long_bitset, don't know the exact name) is optimized for this. You can have a look at the boost documentation; the use cases for which the class is optimized should be mentioned there.

Comment: Since you're worried about performance, it's worth mentioning: Profile the entire application, bottleneck may be somewhere entirely different, and you may need to change your approach to improve performance. And then of course benchmark the actual bit operations, in the real situation.

Comment: Make sure the performance hit of this is crucial before starting fiddling around. The best bet for performance is change approach/algorithm/data structure, only afterwards does it make sense looking for efficient operations (and, except for truly exotic stuff, your compiler will do it for you). Bit fiddling is _expensive_, unless the space savings truly are worth it, leave it alone. Check out Joh Bentley's "Programming Pearls" on performance (his "Writing efficient programs" is out of print).

Comment: @vonbrand, it is not optimizing for space, the reason why I want to give it a try is because I have benchmarked it in small-scale test, the primary advantage of save them in a bit-set is that such that the CPU's cache can accommodate much more of them, nowadays computing resource is plent, it is usually the memory storage who is the performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[GMP](http://gmplib.org/) provides [low level bit functions](http://gmplib.org/manual/Low_002dlevel-Functions.html#Low_002dlevel-Functions) on arbitrarily sized natural numbers. These are "low-level GMP functions, used to implement the high-level GMP functions, but also intended for time-critical user code."

These include `mpn_popcount` to count 1 bits, and `mpn_copyi` to extract sub-sequences.

Comment: Looks very interesting, especially the count function that can count indivial data unit instead of the whole bitset, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [BitMagic library](http://bmagic.sourceforge.net/index.html) might be your friend too.